# Like callback on create/load

Tags: callback, facebook-javascript-sdk, dom-events, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Is there a way to get the like status when the like button is created?  I have the `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create'`... but that only fires when a user clicks the like button. I want to know if they have already liked the site when they come to it.  I can't create an app and require permissions just to get the like status. I need to just be able to get it with the Javascript API.  Is this possible?  Is there another way to tell if a user has liked the website when the like button loads?  It should be noted that this implementation is on a website without PHP and not within Facebook.